# How do I view a csv with column command(bash) but have the header follow as I scroll?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to modify a command like `column -t -s , file.csv | less -S` so that the header in the first line follows when we scroll?

Comment: also found this: [How to scroll large datafile while keeping header](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60507)

Comment: None of these really worked for me.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask a new question and show your coding attempts that didn't work